# How to Fill a Non-Quadrilateral Shape (i.e. a Star) Based on a Percentage Using CSS in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, font-awesome

I'm trying to create a React component that displays a rating percentage in the form of a star with two tones.

Ex. Given a input rating of 79%, I would then display a star with the left 79% as gold and the right 21% as grey.

As of now, I have two separate stars from **Font Awesome** in the same position (one gold and one grey).

My [sandbox is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-williamson-844owh?file=/src/StarRating.js) and code down below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    starFill: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        transition: 'color 200ms',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '25%',
        left: '50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -75%)',
        zIndex: 1
    },
    starContainer: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        transition: 'color 200ms',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '25%',
        left: '50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -75%)',
        zIndex: 2
    }
}));

const StarRating = (percentRating) => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    
    console.log(percentRating);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classes.starFill}>
                <FaStar color='#ffc107' size={200} />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.starContainer}>
                <FaStar color='#e4e5e9' size={200} />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default StarRating;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to accomplish my goal by switching the star's zIndexes, and then changing the width of the star to the percentage and adding `overflow:hidden` to it's style.

my [sandbox is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bash-p844by?file=/src/StarRating.js) and code is down below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    starFill: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        transition: 'color 200ms',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '25%',
        left: '50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -75%)',
        zIndex: 2,
    },
    starContainer: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        transition: 'color 200ms',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '25%',
        left: '50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -75%)',
        zIndex: 1,
    }
}));

const StarRating = ({ rating = 100, size = 200, ...props }) => {

    const classes = useStyles();

    rating = (rating / 100) * size;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classes.starFill}>
                <div style={{ width: rating, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                    <FaStar color='#ffc107' size={size} />
                </div>
                {/* transparent div to reserve the complementary spacing */}
                <div style={{ width: size }}>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.starContainer}>
                <FaStar color='#e4e5e9' size={size} />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default StarRating;
```